# LLVM Pass(Machine Function Pass)

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I want to insert a pass to schedule the code sequences myself before the Machine Instructions has been lower to MCInsts.

How can I do to create a pass at the end of Machine Instructions level?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can use a MachineFunctionPass. MachineFunctionPass basically collects the native code, and so you could work down at the Machine Level. However, the pass works on each MachineFunction independently.